# Is this a suitable use of a transaction to find the serial number of the last person with a shared surname?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to generate an `ApplicantNumber` with three surname digits, then the count of people with that surname. This is my first attempt. I think the serializable transaction should prevent any duplicates. Will it?

```
public string GenerateApplicantNumber(string surname)
{
    using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable}))
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", surname.Substring(0, Math.Min(Regex.Replace(surname, @"\s+", "").Length, 3)),
                                _profileService.ReadApplicantProfiles().Count(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.LastName == surname));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate conflicts in certain cases.

- Assume you have two applicants with the same name "Foo".
- Applicant 1 will get the number "Foo1" and Applicant 2 will get "Foo2".
- Now you set the status of Applicant 1 to deleted.
- A third applicant with the name "Foo" comes into the system.
- The number of undeleted applicants is 2, so the third applicant will also get the number "Foo2", resulting in a conflict.

Comment: Yes, I think I should include deletes applicants in the count. Another improvement I've made is to not only remove whitespace from the name but all non-alpha.

Comment: Accepted for the very valuable warning, even if not a direct answer.